# пронумеровать записи в таблице в соответствии с группировкой в R

Tags: r

Хочу пронумеровать в R каждую запись `SM_MANAGE_CODE` в столбце `CODE` для каждого `APP`. Моя таблица `df` имеет вид:

```
+------+---------------+-------+
|trdate|      CODE     |  APP  |
+------+---------------+-------+
|21:58 |SM_MANAGE_CALL |123453 |
|21:58 |        HUNTER |123453 |
|21:58 |         GFL   |123453 |
|21:59 |SM_MANAGE_CALL |123453 |
|21:59 |        CODWAY |123453 |
|22:00 |        CODWAY |123453 |
|22:02 | SM_MANAGE_CALL|123453 |
|22:02 |         FPS   |123453 |
|8:01  |         GFL   |163452 |
|8:01  | SM_MANAGE_CALL|163452 |
|8:02  |        CODWAY |163452 |
|8:04  |        CODWAY |163452 |
|8:05  | SM_MANAGE_CALL|163452 |
|8:05  |          FPS  |163452 |
|8:07  | SM_MANAGE_CALL|163452 |
|18:15 | SM_MANAGE_CALL|158773 |
|18:15 |          GFL  |158773 |
|18:16 |        HUNTER |158773 |
+------+---------------+-------+
```

Хочу получить такой результат:

```
+------+---------------+-------+
|trdate|      CODE     |  APP  |
+------+---------------+-------+
|21:58 |SM_MANAGE_CALL1|123453 |
|21:58 |        HUNTER |123453 |
|21:58 |         GFL   |123453 |
|21:59 |SM_MANAGE_CALL2|123453 |
|21:59 |        CODWAY |123453 |
|22:00 |        CODWAY |123453 |
|22:02 |SM_MANAGE_CALL3|123453 |
|22:02 |         FPS   |123453 |
|8:01  |         GFL   |163452 |
|8:01  |SM_MANAGE_CALL1|163452 |
|8:02  |        CODWAY |163452 |
|8:04  |        CODWAY |163452 |
|8:05  |SM_MANAGE_CALL2|163452 |
|8:05  |          FPS  |163452 |
|8:07  |SM_MANAGE_CALL3|163452 |
|18:15 |SM_MANAGE_CALL1|158773 |
|18:15 |          GFL  |158773 |
|18:16 |        HUNTER |158773 |
+------+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мое dplyr решение выглядит вот так:

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(trdate = c("21:58","21:58","21:58","21:59","21:59","22:00","22:02","22:02", "8:01", "8:01", "8:02", "8:04", "8:05", "8:05", "8:07", "18:15", "18:15", "18:16"),
       CODE = c("SM_MANAGE_CALL", "HUNTER", "GFL", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "CODWAY", "CODWAY", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "FPS", "GFL", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "CODWAY", "CODWAY", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "FPS", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "SM_MANAGE_CALL", "GFL", "HUNTER"),
       APP = c("123453", "123453", "123453", "123453", "123453", "123453", "123453", "123453", "163452", "163452", "163452", "163452", "163452", "163452", "163452", "158773", "158773", "158773")) %>% 
  group_by(APP, CODE) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% # cоздаем столбец с индексами
  ungroup() %>% # нельзя менять группирующую переменную, так что убираем группировку
  mutate(CODE = ifelse(CODE == "SM_MANAGE_CALL", paste0(CODE, id), CODE)) %>% 
  select(-id) # убираем столбец с индексами

# A tibble: 18 x 3
   trdate CODE            APP   
   <chr>  <chr>           <chr> 
 1 21:58  SM_MANAGE_CALL1 123453
 2 21:58  HUNTER          123453
 3 21:58  GFL             123453
 4 21:59  SM_MANAGE_CALL2 123453
 5 21:59  CODWAY          123453
 6 22:00  CODWAY          123453
 7 22:02  SM_MANAGE_CALL3 123453
 8 22:02  FPS             123453
 9 8:01   GFL             163452
10 8:01   SM_MANAGE_CALL1 163452
11 8:02   CODWAY          163452
12 8:04   CODWAY          163452
13 8:05   SM_MANAGE_CALL2 163452
14 8:05   FPS             163452
15 8:07   SM_MANAGE_CALL3 163452
16 18:15  SM_MANAGE_CALL1 158773
17 18:15  GFL             158773
18 18:16  HUNTER          158773
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью пакета `data.table` решение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```r
library(data.table)
DT[CODE == "SM_MANAGE_CALL", CODE := paste0(CODE, rowid(APP))]
DT
#>     trdate            CODE    APP
#>  1:  21:58 SM_MANAGE_CALL1 123453
#>  2:  21:58          HUNTER 123453
#>  3:  21:58             GFL 123453
#>  4:  21:59 SM_MANAGE_CALL2 123453
#>  5:  21:59          CODWAY 123453
#>  6:  22:00          CODWAY 123453
#>  7:  22:02 SM_MANAGE_CALL3 123453
#>  8:  22:02             FPS 123453
#>  9:   8:01             GFL 163452
#> 10:   8:01 SM_MANAGE_CALL1 163452
#> 11:   8:02          CODWAY 163452
#> 12:   8:04          CODWAY 163452
#> 13:   8:05 SM_MANAGE_CALL2 163452
#> 14:   8:05             FPS 163452
#> 15:   8:07 SM_MANAGE_CALL3 163452
#> 16:  18:15 SM_MANAGE_CALL1 158773
#> 17:  18:15             GFL 158773
#> 18:  18:16          HUNTER 158773
```

Примечания:

- `rowid` генерирует возрастающую последовательность для повторяющихся значений.