# заполнить пустующие значения в R

Tags: r

Есть таблица, где для каждой системы CODE есть время запроса trdate и время ответа repdate.

```
+------+----------------+-------+---------+
|trdate|      CODE      |  APP  | repdate |
+------+----------------+-------+---------+
|21:58 |SM_MANAGE_CALL1 |123453 |    NA   |
|21:58 |        HUNTER  |123453 |   21:59 |
|21:58 |         GFL    |123453 |   21:59 |
|21:59 |SM_MANAGE_CALL2 |123453 |    NA   |
|21:59 |        CODWAY  |123453 |    NA   |
|22:00 |        CODWAY  |123453 |    NA   |
|22:02 | SM_MANAGE_CALL3|123453 |    NA   |
|22:02 |         FPS    |123453 |   22:04 |
|8:01  |         GFL    |163452 |   8:02  |
|8:01  | SM_MANAGE_CALL1|163452 |    NA   |
|8:02  |        CODWAY  |163452 |    NA   |
|8:04  |        CODWAY  |163452 |    NA   |
|8:05  | SM_MANAGE_CALL2|163452 |    NA   |
|8:05  |          FPS   |163452 |   8:06  |
|8:07  | SM_MANAGE_CALL3|163452 |    NA   |
|18:15 | SM_MANAGE_CALL1|158773 |    NA   |
|18:15 |          GFL   |158773 |   18:17 |
|18:16 |        HUNTER  |158773 |   18:17 |
+------+----------------+-------+---------+
```

Нужно заполнить NA-значения repdate следующим временем запроса trdate,вот так:

```
    +------+----------------+-------+---------+
    |trdate|      CODE      |  APP  | repdate |
    +------+----------------+-------+---------+
    |21:58 |SM_MANAGE_CALL1 |123453 |   21:59 |
    |21:58 |        HUNTER  |123453 |   21:59 |
    |21:58 |         GFL    |123453 |   21:59 |
    |21:59 |SM_MANAGE_CALL2 |123453 |   22:00 |
    |21:59 |        CODWAY  |123453 |   22:00 |
    |22:00 |        CODWAY  |123453 |   22:02 |
    |22:02 | SM_MANAGE_CALL3|123453 |    NA   |
    |22:02 |         FPS    |123453 |   22:04 |
    |8:01  |         GFL    |163452 |   8:02  |
    |8:01  | SM_MANAGE_CALL1|163452 |   8:02  |
    |8:02  |        CODWAY  |163452 |   8:04  |
    |8:04  |        CODWAY  |163452 |   8:05  |
    |8:05  | SM_MANAGE_CALL2|163452 |   8:07  |
    |8:05  |          FPS   |163452 |   8:06  |
    |8:07  | SM_MANAGE_CALL3|163452 |    NA   |
    |18:15 | SM_MANAGE_CALL1|158773 |   18:16 |
    |18:15 |          GFL   |158773 |   18:17 |
    |18:16 |        HUNTER  |158773 |   18:17 |
    +------+----------------+-------+---------+
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: А зачем два раза задавать один и тот же вопрос?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067730/

Я уже исправлял сегодня, что этот вопрос никакого отношения не имеет к RStudio.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [пронумеровать записи в таблице в соответствии с группировкой в R](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067730/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-r)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то её можно решить с помощью пакета `data.table` следуюшим образом:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, repdate =: fcoalesce(repdate, shift(trdate, type = "lead")), by = CODE]
```

Примечания:

- `fcoalesce` заменяет пропущенные значения в столбце/векторе на соответствующий элемент другого столбца/вектора.
- `shift` «сдвигает» вектор на указанное количество элементов (по умолчанию - 1) вперёд (`type = "lag"`) или назад (`type = "lead"`).